# call phtml file in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, php

I would like to call the catalog/layer/view.phtml file via ajax.

There is absolutely no change in the code, everything is same but just want to call the view.phtml in ajax.

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

I am going to use the following jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $("#showsearch").load("/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/layer/test.phtml", function(response, status, xhr) {    alert(response);   
});
     });
</script>
<div id="showsearch"></div>
```

I was placing the jquery code in view.phtml but it returns 404 error.

Am I doing something which is completely impossible or it can be done in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you can only `.load()` URLs that you would normally type in your browser's address bar (since JS is client-side). You cannot use absolute file paths of your server this way.

To load this file, you have basically the following options:

1. Place the file above your server's `DocumentRoot` (i.e. most likely where your `index.php` file is, often `public_html` or `www`)
2. Include it using PHP: `<?php include($yourAbsolutePath); ?>`

Since you want to use AJAX to load the file, the best thing you could do is `.load()` a PHP file that is above your `DocumentRoot` and `include()` the file from there.

---

**Example**

1. Create a .php file in your `DocumentRoot` (e.g. myFile.php)
2. Put the following myFile.php:

   ```
   <?php include('/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/layer/test.phtml'); ?>
   ```
3. Change your `.load()` line to:

   ```
   $("#showsearch").load("/myFile.php", function(response, status, xhr) { ...
   ```

Comment: Thanks stardev...Actually the problem is I cannot place the .phtml file under document root.Sorry my fault, I didn't mention that it's the magento system.Also I am not sure if I can use include in a .phtml file.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Magento; however you could still follow the procedure described in the answer. I've added the steps you should take to get it working. Hope this helps.